# How to draw an angle mark like the one in the figure with tikz or tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf

is there a simple way to draw an angle mark like the one in the figure ?
[image: an angle mark]

```
    \documentclass[french,tikz,border=2.5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}% caractères accentués
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontes extended computer modern (EC)
    \usepackage{lmodern} % l'affichage correct des caractères diacritiqués français
    \usepackage{babel}% \usepackage[french]{babel} typographie française


    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,siunitx}

    \usetikzlibrary{quotes ,babel,arrows.meta,angles,calc,shadings,positioning}

    \usetkzobj{all}



    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
            \tkzDefPoint(55:8.8){C}
            \tkzDefPoint(55:5.2){B}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](20:3){B'}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](20:-3){C'}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](180:3){C''}
            \tkzDrawSegment[line cap =round, double distance=3mm](A,C)
            \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
            \begin{scope}[very thick]
            \tkzDrawVector[-Stealth](B',B)
            \tkzDrawVector(C',C)
            \end{scope}

            \tkzLabelPoint(C){\(C\)}
            \tkzLabelPoint(A){\(A\)}
            \tkzLabelPoint(B){\(B\)}

            \draw (C)--(C'');

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you post the code for the rest, somebody can help you mark the angle. Much easier than people having to start from scratch just in order to answer a query about that specific aspect of your project.

Comment: that's right so I post the code!

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. Without that, I would have posted something totally useless to you, since I had no idea how you were drawing the rest ;). [Of course, my suggestion may turn out useless for other reasons anyhow, but at least uselessness is not preordained.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like the following:

- define a couple of extra points, `c1` and `c2` from which the arrows indicating the angle will begin;
- use the `angles` library's `angle` `pic` to draw these arrows in i.e. `C'--C--c2` and `c1--C--C'`, say;
- use a non-drawn `angle` to place the degree label at `C''--C--C'`.

This produces the following result:

[image: marked angle]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,siunitx}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,babel,arrows.meta,angles,positioning}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    angle radius=20mm,
    angle eccentricity=1,
  ]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(55:8.8){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(55:5.2){B}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](20:3){B'}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](20:-3){C'}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](35:-3){c1}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](180:3){C''}
  \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](165:3){c2}
  \tkzDrawSegment[line cap =round, double distance=3mm](A,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
  \begin{scope}[very thick]
    \tkzDrawVector[-Stealth](B',B)
    \tkzDrawVector(C',C)
  \end{scope}
  \tkzLabelPoint(C){\(C\)}
  \tkzLabelPoint(A){\(A\)}
  \tkzLabelPoint(B){\(B\)}
  \draw (C)--(C'');
  \pic ["20\si{\degree}"] {angle = C''--C--C'};
  \pic [draw, {Stealth[]}-] {angle = C'--C--c1};
  \pic [draw, -{Stealth[]}] {angle = c2--C--C''};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great ! but I wonder if there is a way to automate this with a macro or a tikz style ?

Comment: @BoukhouldaHafid Automate what exactly?

Comment: sorry may be my question is not very clear!
how to use a tikz style like \tikzset { myAngleStyle/.style={some code}}

Comment: @BoukhouldaHafid Hmmm.... I will think about it. But I'm not sure that I will come up with anything. I think you would need a different approach which did not rely on the `angle` `pic`. The most obvious strategy would be to create a `pic` but you can't nest such things, so you'd need the `pic` to not use `\pic... {angle = ...}` and I'm not certain how that might be done. I guess you could look at the code for the `angles` library and create a modified form of the `pic` it defines. But it still wouldn't be a *style*. I'm not sure if you could do that, but I'm certain that I don't know how.